# How to copy/transform an AutoValue object with builder

Tags: java, builder, auto-value

I'm playing auto-value with builder recently. And I'm in such a situation, say I have to transform an existing object to a new one with a few properties get updated. The example code is here:

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class SomeObject {
    public static Builder builder() {
      ...
    }

    public abstract String prop1();
    public abstract int prop2();

    // Populate a builder using the current instance.        
    public Builder newBuilder() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Notice I wrote a `newBuilder` method, so that I can do the transformation like this:

```
SomeObject resultedObject = originObject.newBuilder()
    .setProp2(99)
    .build();
```

Yes, I can write the `newBuilder` like this:

```
public Builder newBuilder() {
    return new AutoValue_SomeObject.Builder()
            .setProp1(this.prop1())
            .setProp2(this.prop2());
}
```

But there should be a better way, especially when dealing with complex objects in real life. Something like this is way better:

```
public Builder newBuilder() {
    return new AutoValue_SomeObject.Builder(this);
}
```

Unfortunately, the generated constructor `Builder(SomeObject)` is private, and I cannot find any reference to it.

So what's your thoughts about the problem?

The AutoValue version is `1.4-rc2`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please refer to [JakeWharton's reply](https://github.com/google/auto/issues/455#issuecomment-287513211)

The answer is to declare a `toBuilder` method in `SomeObject`

```
public abstract Builder toBuilder();
```

the generated sub-class will implement this method.